# RGB to YUV420 Planar and Semi-Planar?

Tags: java, android, rgb, android-mediacodec, yuv

In Android, I have a `byte[]` of individual r,g,b,a colors that make up the pixels of an image.

I need to convert these colors to **YUV420 planar or semi-planar** (depending on the device) before I can use Android's MediaCodec and MediaMuxer to create an MP4 of these images.

I'm currently testing on my Nexus 10 which reports that it uses `COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar`.

Here's the code I have to convert RGB to YUV420 **planar**:

```
private void convertRGBAtoYUV420P(byte[] rgba, byte[] yuv, int width, int height)
{
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    final int chromasize = frameSize / 4;

    int yIndex = 0;
    int uIndex = frameSize;
    int vIndex = frameSize + chromasize;

    int R, G, B, Y, U, V;
    int index = 0;

    int rgbaIndex = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            R = rgba[rgbaIndex++] + 128; // My rgba bytes are -128 to 127
            G = rgba[rgbaIndex++] + 128;
            B = rgba[rgbaIndex++] + 128;
            rgbaIndex++; // skip A

            Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
            U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

            yuv[yIndex++] = (byte)clamp(Y);

            if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0)
            {
                yuv[uIndex++] = (byte)clamp(U);
                yuv[vIndex++] = (byte)clamp(V);
            }

            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

I found this code from [this blog](http://embedav.blogspot.com/2013/06/convert-rgb-to-yuv420-planar-format-in.html).

It works, just the color isn't correct. White is gray and all other colors are just wrong. Can't quite figure out what is wrong in the code above, but I feel like it might have to do with the fact that my r,g,b,a bytes are in a range from -128 to 127, but I try to correct that by adding 128 to them.

---

Second question, how would the above code change when I need to convert from RGB to YUV420 **semi-planar** instead?

Comment: Perhaps instead of adding 128 to the byte values do `& 0xff` instead to get a value between `0` and `255`. By adding 128, you're basically cutting out half of the available colors. If you had a Red value of -64 (which is really 192), you're instead getting 64. Or if you had a value of -1 (which would be the max value [255] of a color) by adding 128 you're getting 127.

Comment: @Zymus You're absolutely right. I wasn't really thinking and was just assuming the range was shifted down 128, so just adding 128 would bring it to 0 - 255 like normal. The 0xff mask worked, thanks!

Comment: "It works, just the color isn't correct. White is gray and all other colors are just wrong.": exactly! it works fine

Comment: @gpasch I see how that can sound dumb, but I meant it as in I can actually see the image and make out the objects and whatnot, so the pixel "positional" data was written correctly, just with the wrong color data.

Comment: Your other option is to feed the mediacodec with a Surface. Draw your RGB pixels on the Surface and let the hardware do the YUV conversion. The trick is that you have to use GLES to do it -- Canvas rendering is not supported for this (http://b.android.com/61194).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Just so there's an answer to go with this question.*

The problem is that adding 128 to the byte values doesn't restore it's original value.

Because the color space is defined in values between 0 and 255. They are not simply shifted downwards towards negative number to get it to fit in a signed byte. All of the higher values for the colors (> 127) are encoded to fit in a signed byte, ranging from -128 to -1.

In order to restore the value to what you want, you need to apply the `& 0xff` mask to each of the byte values.